# Android, refresh listview with adapter after user delete item

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I know that there are tons of questions like that. However, I tried them all and nothing helps me.

Thus, I have list of tasks. I store tasks in DB.

That's what I have in onCreate

```
 taskDbHelper = new TaskDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMainScreen);
 final List<Task> list = taskDbHelper.getAllTasks();
 taskListAdapter = new TaskListAdapter(this, list);
 listView.setAdapter(taskListAdapter);
```

If user wants to delete one of tasks I have onLongClickListener for that.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id)
    {
        Task task = list.get(position);
        showEditDialog(task);
        taskListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }

});
```

After that user see dialog fragment where he can confirm or cancel item delete.

If user chose to delete

```
taskDbHelper.deleteTask(getArguments().getString("task"));
MainScreen activity = (MainScreen) getActivity();
activity.onUpdate();
```

As you can see in MainACtivity I call method onUpdate

```
public void onUpdate()
{
    taskListAdapter = new TaskListAdapter(this, taskDbHelper.getAllTasks());
    ((TaskListAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And it doesn't work. I tried almost everything, but it worked only when I added to onUpdate

```
listView.setAdapter(taskListAdapter);
```

However, it looks like really bad solution to me. 
Maybe I am wrong ? And if not, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: also remove the item from List

Comment: It will work when you remove item from adapter list.

Comment: I remove it from DB, and get updated tasks in onUpdate. So I have to remove item from Listview too?

Comment: @AleksanderMonk yes you have to remove it from the list as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the item from you list as well and don't initiate the adapter again.

```
list.remove(task);
((TaskListAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```